# How come my menu and footer have blank spaces?

Tags: html, css

Fairly competent in HTML And CSS would like to find the most compliant way to accomplish this responsively. I would like to make a menu and footer using position:relative. I can't use position:absolute because I want my footer to always be at the bottom of the page according to the content and not disrupt the flow of the DOM. When I use position:relative and width:100%; I noticed my menu and footer have blank spaces on both sides. The menu also has a blank white space at the top, while the footer has a blank white space at the bottom. Hoping one of the experts around here could help me out.

Thanks :)

```css
#mainMenu {
 font-family:Arial, Times, sans-serif;
 list-style-type:none;
 padding-right:30px;
 
} 

#mainMenu a {
text-decoration:none;
margin:5px;
padding:2px;
color:SeaGreen;
font-weight:bold;

}

#mainMenu a:hover {
color:Teal;

}

#menu {
text-align:right;
width:inherit;
height:50px;
background-color:paleGoldenRod;
position:relative;
left:0;
top:0;


}
li {
display:inline;
}


th, td {
text-align:center;
border:1px dashed grey;
width:90px;
height:40px;
}
.formText {
margin:10px 0px;
}
footer {
background-color:SlateGray;
width:100%;
height:100px;
position:relative;
bottom:0;
left:0;



}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
  <title>Contact Me</title>
  <link href="C:\Users\dan\Desktop\Table Generator Website\style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="menu">
      <ul id="mainMenu">
     <li><a href="C:\Users\dan\Desktop\Table Generator Website\index.html">HOME</a></li>
     <li><a href="C:\Users\dan\Desktop\Table Generator Website\About\index.html">ABOUT</a></li>
     <li><a href="C:\Users\dan\Desktop\Table Generator Website\Contact\index.html">CONTACT ME</a></li>
   </ul>
    </div> 
 
    <h2>Contact Me Directly</h2>
 
    <form>
   <label>Full Name:</label><br> <input type="text" name="name" class="formText"><br>
   <label>Your Age:</label><br> <input type="text" name="age" list="ageList" class="formText"><br>
   <datalist id="ageList">
   <option value="18">
   <option value="19">
   <option value="20">
   <option value="21">
   <option value="22">
   </datalist>
   <label>E-Mail:</label><br> <input type="text" name="e-mail" class="formText"><br>
   <label>Your Message</label><br><textarea rows="5" cols="50" class="formText"> </textarea><br>
   <textarea></textarea><br><textarea></textarea>
   
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 
 
 </form>
    <footer>
   <p>This website was designed to learn how to code with proper syntax</p>
 </footer>
 
  </body>

</html>
```

EDIT:Solved by using margin:0; the problem was that my footer and menu were taking the "default" size the body of the document.

One problem still concerns be, Is there a way I could position my menu at the top of the page? Without the blank space above it.

Same goes for the footer I need it to always be at the bottom of the page regardless of the content size on every page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a default `margin` on `body` that is in most/all browsers. To remove it, add `body { margin: 0; }`.

Browsers add default styles to all kinds of elements so that if you just made an HTML page with an `h1`, some `p`'s, and a `ul`, the page would be visually formatted well without any additional styling. You often need to change those default styles when you're styling/designing your own page.

Some people use `* {margin:0;padding:0;}` as a way to remove all default padding and margins from the browser, and if you want a margin/padding on any element, you specify it where you need it.

There are also stylesheet snippets like [reset.css](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) and [normalize](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) that will do this and set a bunch of other defaults that can help with your CSS consistency and differences in browser inconsistencies. You can just copy/paste that code and include it as the first block in your site's CSS.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#mainMenu {
  font-family: Arial, Times, sans-serif;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

#mainMenu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 2px;
  color: SeaGreen;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#mainMenu a:hover {
  color: Teal;
}

#menu {
  text-align: right;
  width: inherit;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: paleGoldenRod;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

li {
  display: inline;
}

th,
td {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px dashed grey;
  width: 90px;
  height: 40px;
}

.formText {
  margin: 10px 0px;
}

footer {
  background-color: SlateGray;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <title>Contact Me</title>
  <link href="C:\Users\dan\Desktop\Table Generator Website\style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="menu">
    <ul id="mainMenu">
      <li><a href="C:\Users\dan\Desktop\Table Generator Website\index.html">HOME</a></li>
      <li><a href="C:\Users\dan\Desktop\Table Generator Website\About\index.html">ABOUT</a></li>
      <li><a href="C:\Users\dan\Desktop\Table Generator Website\Contact\index.html">CONTACT ME</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <h2>Contact Me Directly</h2>

  <form>
    <label>Full Name:</label><br> <input type="text" name="name" class="formText"><br>
    <label>Your Age:</label><br> <input type="text" name="age" list="ageList" class="formText"><br>
    <datalist id="ageList">
   <option value="18">
   <option value="19">
   <option value="20">
   <option value="21">
   <option value="22">
   </datalist>
    <label>E-Mail:</label><br> <input type="text" name="e-mail" class="formText"><br>
    <label>Your Message</label><br><textarea rows="5" cols="50" class="formText"> </textarea><br>
    <textarea></textarea><br><textarea></textarea>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">


  </form>
  <footer>
    <p>This website was designed to learn how to code with proper syntax</p>
  </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is great! Finally I figured out what my problem was. Thank you! The only problem I am still missing is the way to position my menu at the top and footer all the way at the bottom

Comment: @robertlee no problem. Though the way you updated your post just now isn't how Stack Overflow works. You post a question, people post responses, you upvote helpful responses, downvote (or ignore) responses that missed the mark or are wrong, and accept an answer as the solution when the **problem from the original post is solved**. You don't update your post, then change it to ask a new question. You should try to figure out the header/footer thing, and if you can't, post a new question - don't "move the goalpost", so to speak.

Comment: I understand now Michael. :) Thanks for the excellent solution anyway.

Comment: @GibralterTop excuse me? what are you talking about?

Comment: @GibralterTop you think I "stole" your answer? I edited my answer after posting it initially and added the details about reset/normalize details. No one "stole" anything from you. The edits don't even show up in the revision history because it was so quickly after I posted, and if you look at the timestamp on that post, it's 18:13:39. Your answer was 2 minutes after that at 18:15:36. Don't be so presumptuous and accusatory.

Answer (score 1):

To add to @Michael Coker's answer, there is default styling applied to all browsers.

A common practice is to add a reset css file to your project. A good one is here: [reset css](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

Answer (score 0):

Add margin:0; to your body style and if you want menu to always be at bottom, use position: fixed;

Answer (score 0):

```css
#mainMenu {
 font-family:Arial, Times, sans-serif;
 list-style-type:none;
 padding-right:30px;
 
} 

#mainMenu a {
text-decoration:none;
margin:5px;
padding:2px;
color:SeaGreen;
font-weight:bold;

}

#mainMenu a:hover {
color:Teal;

}

#menu {
text-align:right;
width:inherit;
height:50px;
background-color:paleGoldenRod;
position:relative;
left:0;
top:0;


}
li {
display:inline;
}


th, td {
text-align:center;
border:1px dashed grey;
width:90px;
height:40px;
}
.formText {
margin:10px 0px;
}
footer {
background-color:SlateGray;
width:100%;
height:100px;
position:relative;
bottom:0;
left:0;



}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
  <title>Contact Me</title>
  <link href="C:\Users\dan\Desktop\Table Generator Website\style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="menu">
      <ul id="mainMenu">
     <li><a href="C:\Users\dan\Desktop\Table Generator Website\index.html">HOME</a></li>
     <li><a href="C:\Users\dan\Desktop\Table Generator Website\About\index.html">ABOUT</a></li>
     <li><a href="C:\Users\dan\Desktop\Table Generator Website\Contact\index.html">CONTACT ME</a></li>
   </ul>
    </div> 
 
    <h2>Contact Me Directly</h2>
 
    <form>
   <label>Full Name:</label><br> <input type="text" name="name" class="formText"><br>
   <label>Your Age:</label><br> <input type="text" name="age" list="ageList" class="formText"><br>
   <datalist id="ageList">
   <option value="18">
   <option value="19">
   <option value="20">
   <option value="21">
   <option value="22">
   </datalist>
   <label>E-Mail:</label><br> <input type="text" name="e-mail" class="formText"><br>
   <label>Your Message</label><br><textarea rows="5" cols="50" class="formText"> </textarea><br>
   <textarea></textarea><br><textarea></textarea>
   
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 
 
 </form>
    <footer>
   <p>This website was designed to learn how to code with proper syntax</p>
 </footer>
 
  </body>

</html>
```